# reading from excel and converting the data to dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix

I have some data in excel which represents information about a graph and it looks like this:

```
1  2  4.5
1  3  6.6
2  4  7.3
3  4  5.1
```

The first two elements in each row are edges of the graph and the last element is the weight of the arc between those two edges. For example, edge "1" is connected to edge "2" and the weight is 4.5

I import this data into python by the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

training_data_x = pd.read_excel("/Users/mac/Downloads/navid.xlsx",header=None)

x= training_data_x.as_matrix()
```

So "x" here is the adjacency matrix of the graph.
What I am trying to do is converting x to list of dictionaries in python which I need in another code.
I am kind of new to python but I think a dictionary that suits here kind of looks like this

```
gr = {'1': {'2': 4.5, '3': 6.6},
      '2': {'4': 7.3},
      '3': {'4':5.1}}
```

In fact "gr"  should be output of my code here.
I think I should use ""pandas.DataFrame.to_dict"' but I have hard time using this command.  I really appreciate your help here.

Comment: I'm not sure `x` is actually an adjacency matrix, as it is commonly understood.

Comment: Yes. I see what you mean. But my question still exists which is how to convert x here to dictionary as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice: save your `xlsx` file as a `csv`. Now, using vanilla Python:

```
import csv
gr = {}
with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        e1, e2, w = row
        gr.setdefault(e1, {})[e2] = float(w)
```

Perhaps even better, use a `defaultdict`:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
gr = defaultdict(dict)
with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        e1, e2, w = row
        gr[e1][e2] = float(w)
```

EDIT: Note, I have converted to `float` manually, but you can probably get away with simply passing the following argument to `csv.reader`: `csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)` if you don't mind having your keys be floats as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I missed the last part that you mentioned about the float. What do you mean by converting  to float? Also I appreciate if you explain to me about bypassing this conversion and what should I do?

Comment: @navid because you want string keys and float values for the innermost dictionaries, right? That is exactly what you have written. The `csv` module doesn't do automatic conversion, so you can either get *everything* converted to floats by passing the quoting parameter or do it manually as I demonstrated. I would use the second version.

Comment: @navid also, you should check out the current version, cleaned up a bug that you might not have noticed

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to rely on pandas' great groupby/split/combine functionality ([see more here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)) in addition to the *pandas.DataFrame.to_dict* method you could actually do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = "/Users/mac/Downloads/navid.xlsx"
gr = pd.read_excel(file_path, header=None, index_col=0) \ 
   .groupby(level=0) \ 
   .apply(lambda x: dict(x.to_records(False))) \
   .to_dict()
```

This should work for all pandas versions above 0.17.

Comment: Your `apply` was very clever.